# How to show the timezone offset in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I am using time_zone_select to save users timezones.

```
          <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">

              <div class="panel-heading">
                <%= f.label :time_zone, "TimeZone*" %>
              </div>  

              <div class="panel-body">   
                <%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, nil, {}, { :class => 'form-control' } %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

The users timezones are saving successfully in a string.

```
>> userp.time_zone
=> "Chennai"
```

Now when I display the user timezone I want to display the timezone offset like this

```
(GMT+05:30) Chennai
```

This is view template but I am not able to manipulate the timezone since it's stored as a string.

```
      <div>
        <small>
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span style="padding-left:1px">TimeZone:</span>            
        <%= @user.time_zone %>
        </small>
      </div>
```

Can someone guide me, how to display timezone with offset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can treat `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` as an array with `ActiveSupport::TimeZone[named_zone]`, e.g.:

```
  <div>
    <small>
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span style="padding-left:1px">TimeZone:</span>            
    <%= ActiveSupport::TimeZone[@user.time_zone].to_s %> <%= @user.time_zone %>
    </small>
  </div>
```

You can test it in Rails console:

```
[6] pry(main)> ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Chennai"].to_s
=> "(GMT+05:30) Chennai"
```

Please take a note that if you don't use `#to_s`, you will get the `TimeZone` object, which is not what you want. You can see [detailed implementation on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c02f3ea5e31677e7953abee5a1a2d5398d85ad47/activesupport/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb).

Slightly related, If you wonder why this module can be treated as an array, it is because it implements the `[]()` method.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm. Perfect. I removed to_s and after reading the answer completely, I put it back in. Perfect complete answer.